# Access VBA To Add SUM() To Query String

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2013

I have a listbox that is multi-select and essentially builds a query.  The syntax works as it should, but instead of a line by line entry for each `sale` how could I check if the array contains the field `sale` and if it does alter the text to `SUM(Sales) As SaleAmt`?

This is my current syntax:

```
    Dim I As Long 
Dim X As Long 
Dim arrValues() 
If lstQueryBuild.ListIndex <> -1 Then 
    For I = 0 To lstQueryBuild.ListCount - 1 
        If lstQueryBuild.Selected(I) Then 
            Redim Preserve arrValues(X) 
            arrValues(X) = lstQueryBuild.List(I) 
            X = X + 1 
        End If 
    Next I 
End If 

CurrentDb.Exeucte "Select " & Join(arrValues, ",") & " FROM holdingtable"
```

Which will produce

```
Debug.Print produces Select name, address, phone, company, sales from holdingtable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try substituting your `Join()` function with a loop through your array.

```
dim sSQL$

sSQL="Select "

For x=lbound(arrValues) to ubound(arrvalues)
if arrValues(x)="sales" then 
     sSQL=sSQL & "sum(Sales),"
else
     sSQL=sSQL & arrValues(x) & ","
end if
next x

ssQL=left(sSQL,len(ssql)-1) & " from holdingtable"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
```